# why lambda x: x % 2 means odd number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> fibonacci = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
>>> odd_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2, fibonacci))
>>> print(odd_numbers)
[1, 1, 3, 5, 13, 21, 55]
>>> even_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, fibonacci))
>>> print(even_numbers)
[0, 2, 8, 34]
```

why not like this: lambda x: x % 2 == 1

Comment: Even though the `== 1` isn't necessary, I'd definitely still include it for explicitness. The four key strokes you save isn't worth the potential extra seconds it takes to comprehend when reading. That could just be me too, since the language I'm most familiar with doesn't have 0 as falsey.

Comment: Python is one of those languages where all values can be implicitly cast to a boolean depending on their type (i.e. everything is either "truthy" or "falsy"). For numbers, a value is falsy if it's 0 and truthy otherwise. Any odd number modulo 2 is 1, which is therefore considered truthy.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `x % 2` will be read as a boolean and 0 is false and 1 is true (like every number different of 0).

You can try it with

```
print (True == 1)  # True
print (False == 0) # True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQSOkqDRVwdZWwVCTCyrilphTDBYy0Pz/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

In boolean context, non-zero is true (and zero is false). Your version is quite legal as well, it's mostly save some typing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because (x % 2) would return 1 if x is divisible by 2 else 0.Now in Boolean context
1 is for True and 0 is for False.Therefore, in filter function we use only `x%2` for getting the odd numbers, because it will give 0(`False`) if it is divisible by 2 else 1(`True`).

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is due to filter function rather than lambda here.
filter definition:

> As the name suggests, filter creates a list of elements for which a function returns true.
>
> filter(func, iterable) ---> func is the function which will be executed on iterable.

So now lets see how will filter work in this case.

```
fibonacci = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
odd_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2, fibonacci))
# For each element in fibonacci:
# x = fibonacci[0]
# lambda x: x % 2 will return 0 which is equivalent to False
# Now filter will ignore this as the result of filter is False
# Next Iteration: x = fibonacci[1]
# lambda x: x % 2 will return 1 which is equivalent to True
# So filter will get this value
# therefore, odd_numbers = [1]
# So on and so forth.
```

Hope it helps.